# How to factorize fraction by a given symbol?

Tags: python, math, sympy, fractions

I have the following fraction:

```
import sympy as sp
a = sp.Symbol("a")
b = sp.Symbol("b")

a/(a+b)
```

And would like to print it as
`1/(1+b/a)`

I saw sympy had a `factor` function but I couldn't obtain the expected behaviour.

I thought I could maybe do something like:

```
sp.factor((a/(a+b)), a)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would call this "distributing the numerator in the denominator":

```py
>>> a/(a + b)
>>> 1/expand(1/_)
1/(1 + b/a)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

This works perfectly for this simple example.
My use case is a tad more complex:
a b / (a c + d) and I'd like to factorise by a. Unfortunately your answer gives it in the form 1/X.

Maybe there isn't a way to achieve this in sympy.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "factorise by a". If you mean "distribute `a` in denominator" then `did=lambda eq, a: numer(eq)/a/expand(denom(eq)/a); did(eq, a)` gives `b/(c + d/a)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use expand and collect

```
import sympy as sp


a = sp.Symbol("a")
b = sp.Symbol("b")


expanded = sp.expand(a/(a+b))

collected = sp.collect(expanded, a)

print(collected)
```